# Image flipping incorrectly...Why?

Tags: c, image, struct, flip

I am trying to flip my image on a Y Axis, and it does flip, but it leaves odd spaces in the middle and on the right side, it wont flip the entire image perfectly, I am limiting the images to 450 by 450 and a P3...Anyone have any ideas, because my algorithm is correct

```
for(j=0; j < imgur.width/2; j++)
  {
     for(i=0; i < imgur.height; i++)
        {
           temp.red = imgur.image[i][j].red;
           imgur.image[i][j].red = imgur.image[i][imgur.height-j-1].red;
           imgur.image[i][imgur.height-j-1].red = temp.red;

           temp.green = imgur.image[i][j].green;
           imgur.image[i][j].green = imgur.image[i][imgur.height-j-1].green;
           imgur.image[i][imgur.height-j-1].green = temp.green;

           temp.blue = imgur.image[i][j].blue;
           imgur.image[i][j].blue = imgur.image[i][imgur.height-j-1].blue;
           imgur.image[i][imgur.height-j-1].blue = temp.blue;
     }
  }
```

Here's my algorithm... Before that I am printing out the P3, the comment, the width and height, and the maxColor. I am using two structs to get the data and reading in a file from the terminal...
Here's how I'm printing out the data. Anyone have any ideas?

```
 for(i=imgur.height-1; i >= 0; i--)
  {
     for(j=0; j < imgur.width; j++)
        {
           printf("%i\n", imgur.image[i][j].red);
           printf("%i\n", imgur.image[i][j].green);
           printf("%i\n", imgur.image[i][j].blue);
        }
  }
```

Comment: Is it normal to read the image in a flipped way when printing it? You read from the last line to the first one.

Comment: @Bentoy13 printing and scanning(which I didn't include), I am scanning and printing in from the highest point at column 0 and row 0 and incrementing down as I print/scan in the data. My goal is to ultimately flip the image, by moving the pixels on the right side, to the left side.

Comment: Hum, for me the highest point of an image is located at `image[0][0]`. Here you start printing at `image[imgur.height-1][0]`. Is it really what you want to do?

Comment: @Bentoy13 Because I am moving from the highest point, -1 thats why I start at the height -1 so for every previous pixel, it will flip with the following

Answer (score 1):

my symmetric detector is confused by (in the upper part)

```
for(j=0; j < imgur.width/2; j++) {
  for(i=0; i < imgur.height; i++) {
```

and (in the lower part)

```
for(i=imgur.height-1; i >= 0; i--) {
  for(j=0; j < imgur.width; j++) {
```

Comment: printing and scanning(which I didn't include), I am scanning and printing in from the highest point at column 0 and row 0 and incrementing down as I print/scan in the data. But I flipped within the algorithm itself which is the for(j=0 < imgur.width/2 etc... because it actually flipped the image, where before i had it i=0; i <imgur.width/2; etc...

Answer (score 1):

You have made a little typo mistake in the flip algorithm: as you flip upside-down, you have to scan all lines entirely and half of the height of the image, not the inverse.

```
for(j=0; j < imgur.width; j++)
{
  for(i=0; i < imgur.height/2; i++)
  {
     //code of your loop, removed for compactness
  }
}
```

**EDIT**
In fact, for left-right swapping, you have also inverted the complement of index `j`. `j` is along the X-axis, belonging the range `0:width-1`, so the complement is `width-1-j`.

I have coded a version of this algorithm a long time ago, it was like that:

```
for (i=0; i!=h; i++) {
    for (j=0; j!=w/2; j++) {
        temp = src[i][w-1-j];
        dst[i][w-1-j] = src[i][j];
        dst[i][j] = temp;
    }
}
```

I think it works fine (As you are working with a pixel struct, it is perfectly correct to swap the whole pixel like this).

Comment: If I'm flipping on the Y axis though, I believe i move via height not width, ultimately flipped as I do down.

Comment: If you flip along Y-axis, you swap left and right part of the image. If you flip along X-axis, you swap top and bottom part of the image. It is not really related to the way you scan the image.

Comment: And how do you define Y and X axes?

Comment: Ah ok I have it. So your mistake is in the `for` statements. I correct my answer; my comments are irrelevant then, sorry.

Comment: Hey! Don't worry about it, I am glad for any help that I can get!!

Comment: I just appreciate the input. Where in my for statement did I mess up?

Comment: I just update my answer (sorry for the delay, some problems with my connection). Both of them in fact :)

Comment: Hey, so i tried you're theory, and I ended up switching j and i around because they were also backwards but i dvided height by 2 and it still will give me the majority of the image flipped, except for the last little bit, though the line in the middle is gone.